# rails has_one remove link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, belongs-to, has-one

Is the only way to destroy an association of a has_one and belongs_to by setting the FK to nil on the belongs_to object?

Comment: note - I do not want to delete either object

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't setting `@obj1.obj2 = nil` work?

But this doesn't delete the belongs_to record. If you want to do it you need to do `@obj1.obj2.delete`

Comment: Correct, this is the method i refer to in the question.

Comment: @Mike: So..does it not work, or what? You have a solution, what's your question?

Comment: Is the only way to destroy an association of a has_one and belongs_to by setting the FK to nil on the belongs_to object?

Comment: You can also do @obj1.obj2.delete if you want to DELETE the belongs_to object, as edited in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since I remenber, once you set drop in cascade, you just have to delete the object and it deletes all dependencies.

Hope this helps,
Cheers